# unstack multiindex dataframe to flat data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a multi index df called groupt3 in pandas which looks like this when I enter groupt3.head():

```
                datetime     song   sum   rat
artist datetime
2562     8      2            2      26    0
         46     19           19     26    0
         47     3            3      26    0
4Hero    1      2            2      32    0
         26     20           20     32    0
         9      10           10     32    0
```

I would like to have a "flat" data frame which took the artist index and the date time index and "repeats it" to form this:

```
artist     date time    song   sum   rat
2562       8            2      26    0
2562       46           19     26    0
2562       47           3      26    0
```

etc...

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how you have datetime as a column and index but you can call `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` to achieve what you want, see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749309/pandas-dataframe-sort-want-to-sum-and-sort-but-keep-column-names/22749426#22749426

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [pandas.DataFrame.to_records()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html).

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [['Monday','Monday','Tursday','Tursday'],
                        ['Morning','Noon','Morning','Evening']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Weekday', 'Time'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(4,2)), index=index)

In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
                 0  1
Weekday Time         
Monday  Morning  1  3
        Noon     2  1
Tursday Morning  3  3
        Evening  1  2

In [40]: pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
Out[40]: 
   Weekday     Time  0  1
0   Monday  Morning  1  3
1   Monday     Noon  2  1
2  Tursday  Morning  3  3
3  Tursday  Evening  1  2
```

Answer (score 12):

I think you can use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
arrays = [['Monday','Monday','Tursday','Tursday'],
                        ['Morning','Noon','Morning','Evening']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Weekday', 'Time'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(4,2)), index=index)
print df
                 0  1
Weekday Time         
Monday  Morning  4  0
        Noon     3  3
Tursday Morning  3  1
        Evening  3  2

print df.reset_index()
   Weekday     Time  0  1
0   Monday  Morning  4  0
1   Monday     Noon  3  3
2  Tursday  Morning  3  1
3  Tursday  Evening  3  2
```